# Does Captain Rex know who is Darth Vader?

Tags: star-wars

In the trailer for Star Wars Rebels season 2, we can see that Captain Rex survived the Clone Wars and most probably deserted. As a captain of the 501st reporting directly to Anakin Skywalker, he and the rest of the battalion knows the attack on the Jedi Temple is to be led by Darth Vader. Once he meets the Sith Lord in the flesh, it is impossible he would not recognise the Republic's poster boy he fought alongside for 3 years.

So the question is: Was Rex still there when Order 66 was executed, or did he desert before that? If he is indeed aware of who Darth Vader is, then I think it has major implications as I think he'll eventually mention it to Ahsoka.

imo, he likely deserted only after Order 66, as: 1) he had demonstrated conviction in the values of the Republic  he was supposedly defending, so it's unlikely he would abandon it 2) he's somewhat close to Anakin, so there's nothing to emotionally shatter his blind loyalty...yet 3) his inhibitor chip is likely undamaged.

I think what made him lose his loyalty is the events of the Republic's fall and the Empire's rise, but at a more gradual pace, eventually shaking him up. Ofc, all these are pure conjecture, but what do you think?

Edit: Just saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZ7S2rNUjYM). It appears that Captain Rex and a few others had their inhibitor chips removed, as pointed out in the video. Still not convinced he deserted before or upon Order 66 and did not execute it, though. It's still pure conjecture as to when exactly he removed the inhibitor chip, I think

Comment: I think this is too speculative/opinion based to be properly answered.

Comment: Order 66 wasn't issued to the 501st, was it? They were marching with Anakin/Vader to the Jedi temple to kill the younglings and the rest of the Jedi. I always assumed they continued working with Vader after his transformation.

Comment: VTCing as opinion-based per our [future works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based). Once the relevant episode of *Rebels* airs, and this question is answerable, it can be re-opened

Answer (score 0):

**This would be difficult to answer without knowing of Rex's exact whereabouts during Order 66.**

Unless he was one of the 501st who attacked the Jedi Temple with Anakin, it's not unreasonable to suggest that he - along with most of the galaxy - has no idea Vader is actually Anakin.

As far as we know from canon, the last time Rex interacted with Skywalker was at The Battle of Quell. Therefore, there is no reason to believe that neither Rex, nor his friends Wolffe and Gregor (also defected Clone Troopers), would have access to Vader's true identity. He would most likely believe the Imperial propaganda which states that Anakin Skywalker died as a Jedi Knight.

[image]

Needless to say, this may change in a future episode. Until we learn more, we may have to assume that Rex and his two co-horts have been

> living in the abandoned AT-TE since the Republic fell.